# fabric run fork

Tags: python, fabric, fork

I want to use Fabric.api.run to directly start an application in a remote box. Since the application takes really a long to finish, I wish to be able to fork a child process, such that I don't need to wait for a long time.

The code is like:

```
from fabric.api import run
....

run("python ./myApp.py --fork=True >myApp.log 2>&1")
```

I used the following code to enable forking side the code:

```
if settings.fork:
    child_pid = os.fork()
    if child_pid == 0:
        print "Starting Child Process: PID# %s" % os.getpid()
    else:
        print "Terminating Parent Process: PID# %s" % os.getpid()
        os._exit(0)
```

The problem is after I do the run command, I sshed into the remote box, and found out the program has been quit for some unknown reason, I check the log file, there is nothing there.

Somebody could let me know how I can work this around? Many thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talking of forks, there is a fork of Fabric that enables parallel execution, apart from lots of other improvements.

http://tav.espians.com/fabric-python-with-cleaner-api-and-parallel-deployment-support.html

Depending on what you are doing, you may want to consider that.

---

Apart from that, I think you want to use `multiprocessing`:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
    print 'hello', name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    #p.join()
```

http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: Fabric definitely needs parallel execution in some form.

Comment: Parallel deployment/execution is awesome which can I will definitely try out. But my problem is when I need to use "run" to run program in remote box, I am wondering how to make the program continuously run even though fabric's run command has returned (My example is doing os.fork() inside the program to fork a child process, and redirecting all output/error to a log file.)

Comment: For those who run into the same pitfall, just use python-daemon to replace os.fork(). This works for me.